# UISegmented Control subviews not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I am attempting to use an UISegmentedControl to switch between three views. I have the first view within a container view on the main viewcontroller. I then created two other views on separate viewcontrollers. I programmed subviews for these two views within the main viewcontroller's container.

The issue I'm having is that the second two views won't show up when I switch the segmented control. The segment changes the container and hides the first view but the second two are not appearing.

I was able to use this method when I had the second two views created through .xib files. Problem is now I have them as viewcontrollers on the storyboard instead.

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet var segment: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet var detailsView: UIView!

@IBOutlet var segmentView: UIView!
var viewTwo: UIView!
var viewThree: UIView!

@IBAction func segmentChange(_ sender: Any) {

    switch(segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

        detailsView.isHidden = false
        segmentView.isHidden = true

        break

    case 1:

        detailsView.isHidden = true
        segmentView.isHidden = false
        segmentView.bringSubviewToFront(viewTwo)

        break

    case 2:

        detailsView.isHidden = true
        segmentView.isHidden = false
        segmentView.bringSubviewToFront(viewThree)

        break

    default:
        detailsView.isHidden = false
        segmentView.isHidden = true
        break

    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewTwo = ShowtimesView().view
    segmentView.addSubview(viewTwo)
    viewThree = ReviewsView().view
    segmentView.addSubview(viewThree)


}
```

Comment: ShowtimesView and ReviewsView are view controller and it's not init using storyboard or xib and it's view is empty so it's not displaying. 
Please check after changing bg color of viewTwo and  viewThree at viewDidLoad

Comment: This code worked perfectly fine when the two subview viewcontrollers were .xib files. I am only having this issue when the view controllers are apart of the stroyboard rather than .xib files. I am not sure why since all the code is the exact same. The only difference is storyboard vs .xib file.

Comment: how you can init view controller in xib?.
did you do any code inside ShowtimesView's init method?.
 your code  not init viewController from stotyboard or xib just created ViewController's instance  with it default view Property.

Comment: It is not required to use init with swift 4. The above code worked when my controllers were .xib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a container for each of the subview viewcontrollers in the original viewcontroller. I also made sure to add the proper names to their storyboard id's not only their classes.

Here is the working code:

```
@IBOutlet var segment: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet var detailsView: UIView!


@IBOutlet var showtimeView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var reviewView: UIView!
var viewTwo: UIView!
var viewThree: UIView!

@IBAction func segmentChange(_ sender: Any) {

    switch(segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

        detailsView.isHidden = false
        showtimeView.isHidden = true
        reviewView.isHidden = true            

        break

    case 1:

        detailsView.isHidden = true
        showtimeView.isHidden = false
        reviewView.isHidden = true

        break

    case 2:

        detailsView.isHidden = true
        showtimeView.isHidden = true
        reviewView.isHidden = false

        break

    default:
        detailsView.isHidden = false
        showtimeView.isHidden = true
        reviewView.isHidden = true
        break

    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewTwo = ShowtimesView().view
    showtimeView.addSubview(viewTwo)
    viewThree = ReviewsView().view
    reviewView.addSubview(viewThree)


}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are saying things like `ShowtimesView().view`. That is not how to load a view controller from a storyboard! You need to talk to the storyboard and instantiate the view controller.

Even then, however, what you are doing is totally wrong. You cannot use a view controller to "dumpster-dive" for its view and stuff that view wantonly into your interface. You must make yourself into a custom parent view controller and make the other view controller your child. There is a formal dance you have to do, and you are not doing the dance.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the code below.

```
@IBOutlet var segment: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet var segmentView: UIView!

var viewOne: UIView!
var viewTwo: UIView!
var viewThree: UIView!

@IBAction func segmentChange(_ sender: Any) {

    switch(segment.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:
        segmentView.bringSubviewToFront(viewOne)
        break

    case 1:
        segmentView.bringSubviewToFront(viewTwo)
        break

    case 2:
        segmentView.bringSubviewToFront(viewThree)
        break

    default:
        segmentView.bringSubviewToFront(viewOne)
        break
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewOne = DetailView().view
    segmentView.addSubview(viewOne)
    viewTwo = ShowtimesView().view
    segmentView.addSubview(viewTwo)
    viewThree = ReviewsView().view
    segmentView.addSubview(viewThree)

    segmentView.bringSubviewToFront(viewOne)
}
```

Comment: DetailView is apart of the original viewcontroller and appears fine. It is already a subview. This is why I chose to hide it rather than move it behind the two subviews.

Answer (score 0):

you need to code for init view controller from storyboard like :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    viewTwo = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ShowtimesView") as! ShowtimesView).view
    segmentView.addSubview(viewTwo)
    viewThree = (UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ReviewsView") as! ReviewsView).view
    segmentView.addSubview(viewThree)
}
```

1 "Main" is your StoryBoard Name 
2 "ShowtimesView" is storyboard id like: 
 [image]